# Как правильно обработать объект?

Tags: php

три объекта которые хранатся в переменной `image`

```
object(ImageClass)#1 (1){
    ["name"]=>"one";
    ["forHome"]=>0;
}
object(ImageClass)#1 (2){
    ["name"]=>"two";
    ["forHome"]=>1;
}
object(ImageClass)#1 (3){
    ["name"]=>"three";
    ["forHome"]=>0;
}
```

мне надо вывести  циком foreach так? что бы первым отобразился объект со значением `forHome` равным 0 условно говоря вот таким кодом

```
foreach($image as $img){
'Name :". $img->name ." for home :".$img->forHome
}
```

Comment: в чем загвоздка то?

Comment: @teran исправил

Comment: дак сложите объекты в массив, если они еще не в массиве, отсортируйте с помощью `usort` и выведите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если взять ваш исходный класс следующего вида:

```
class Image {
    public $name;
    public $forHome;
}
```

Сформировать тестовый массив:

```
$data = [];
$n = rand(3,10);
while($n--){
    $img  = new Image();
    $img->name = "image-$n";
    $img->forHome = rand(0,1);
    $data[] = $img;
}
```

то далее необхоимо отсортировать массив по значению вашего поля объекта. Для этих целей используется функция [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php), первым аргументом которой является сортируемый массив, передавайемый по ссылке, вторым - функция обратоного вызова, принимающая как аргумент 2 значения из массива (объекта) и сравнивающая их. Сравнивать надо значения. В таких функция принято возвращать значение 0 если элементы равны, или значения `1` или `-1`, в случае больше/меньше. Чаще возвращают просто разницу между ними. В PHP7 для этих целей введен специальный оператор `<=>`:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b){ 
                return $a->forHome -  $b->forHome; 
     });
```

Очевидно, что если порядок следования элементов нужно сохранить, а лишь вывести "нулевые" элементы в начале, то сортировка будет не совсем подходящим решением для задачи. Хотя если нумерация объектов хранится, то этого достаточно. 
В противном случае можно переместить элементы с нулевым значением вперед массива, например, следующим образом:

```
$result = ['zero' => null, 'nonzero' => null];
foreach($data as $img){
    $key = $img->forHome ? 'nonzero' : 'zero';
    $result[$key][] = $img;
}
$data = array_merge($result['zero'], $result['nonzero']);
```

В таком случае исходный порядок следования элементов будет сохранен.

Конечно, банально задачу можно решить и двумя циклами вывода. В первом вывести только нулевые, а во втором наобоорот.

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = array(/* ваши объекты */);
usort($images, function($a, $b) { 
    if ($a->forHome == $b->forHome) 
        return 0;
    else 
        (return $a->forHome > $b->forHome) ? 1 : -1;
});
```